# put order of cell values in cells above

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a row with random numbers and want to put their order (smallest first):
[image]

In this example, the random numbers are in row 2 and their order is in row 1.  Note that columns A and C both have the same values and therefore have the same ranking.

I am not opposed to doing this as a function, but I am looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a rank function!

```
=rank(A2,$A2:$F2,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the RANK function, I believe you'll wind up with no rank of `4` in your sample scenario, given the two ties at rank `3`.

If you don't care about that, you can use an array formula that will deliver all results at once. Clear *all of Row 1* and then put this formula in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula(RANK(FILTER(2:2,2:2<>""),FILTER(2:2,2:2<>""),1))`

This formula will deliver all results *and* it will continue to rank if more numbers are added into Row 2.

If you *do* care about missing rankings when there is a tie, you can still use an array formula; it's just a bit more complex. Again, clear all of Row 1 and place the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(FILTER(2:2,2:2<>""),{SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,2:2<>"")))),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,2:2<>"")))))},2,FALSE))`

This is one of many approaches.

The section between the curly brackets `{ }` will form an ascending sorted unique list of the numbers to the left of a sequence of numbers that starts at one and goes as high as the number of elements in the sorted unique list beside it.

`FILTER` considers only those cells in Row 2 (i.e., `2:2`) that are not null, which will continue to expand as new cells are added.

`VLOOKUP` will look up each value in the first column of the virtual array held between those curly brackets and return the number in column 2 (i.e., the rank).

This formula assumes that any cells in Row 2 will be contiguous and will be real numbers. If for some reason that isn't the case, the following error controls will allow for gaps or non-numerical entries in Row 2 while still returning the rank of all numbers:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(2:2,{SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,ISNUMBER(2:2))))),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(2:2,ISNUMBER(2:2))))))},2,FALSE)))`